# 2013 Late Macbook Pro constantly mute completely?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, sleep-wake

I find there are some cases where my Macbook becomes completely mute, meaning each application cannot make any sound. Even while adjusting the volume, there is no sound during the operation.

One already spotted action that leads to this case is I make it sleep first, and then wake it up. Then, the computer is completely mute. I am sure there are some other cases.

The only solution is restarting the computer.

How may I fix it? Bring it to AppleCare?

Comment: next time it happens can you try running https://gist.github.com/dstarh/09d7577c333bf336e92a This will cause core audio to restart which could possibly be an issue.  I have a similar issue where audio will refuse to play over airplay and this always fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting AppleCare, I finally solved this issue perfectly. I post my solution here so that the future users may solve it easily when they reach Apple S.X..

Delete two files:

`com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings` and `com.apple.audio.SystemSettings`.

Then do the NVRAM restarting to your MacBook to reset the audio settings. Detailed steps to do the NVRAM restarting is [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

Then, problem solved.

Comment: Where is these files located ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this occur when you have stereo or headphones plugged into the jack, or only when using the computer's speakers?

If it is only when trying to use the built-in speakers, then probably there is some dirt or lint in your headphone jack outlet, and the computer thinks that something is plugged in there.

You can try compressed air (safe) or a paperclip (not as safe), or just go to the Genius Bar and let them sort it out.